# How to convert a List with two capsuled tuples insed it to list?

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, tuples

I have a list which has capsuled two tuples inside of it.

Example:

```
[(('100.100.100.100', 11111), ('100.100.100.100', 11111))]
```

And I need to convert it like this:

```
['100.100.100.100', '100.100.100.100']
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
l1 = [(('100.100.100.100', 11111), ('100.100.100.100', 11111))]
l2 = [l[0] for l in l1[0]]
print(l2)

# Output:
['100.100.100.100', '100.100.100.100']
```

Comment: @Corralien No problem. :)